# how to get the roots of x using newton raphson method in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
a=2

b=3

c=7

d=5

w=14
```

Find x using newton raphson method in matlab

```
enter code here
4.w.d^2.(1-x^2)^2=a.b.c^3.x.sqrt(pi^2.(1-x^2)^2+16.x^2)
```

Comment: I have a very, very strong suspicion that this needs a "homework" tag.  Also, what have you tried?  What specific problems are you having?  We aren't here to code for you, we're here to help.

Comment: Instead of giving a -1 and further downvotes. Please migrate this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/. I dont have that privilige.

Comment: @Yavar: this is very much a Matlab question, and a badly formulated one at that. I don't think this question would be of interest to math.stackexchange.com, nor that the answers would be of use to the OP.

Comment: @jonas: you are absolutely right i think when the question was posted it did not have matlab in subject so commented like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **ton** of posts similar to this, even on StackOverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639504/newton-raphsons-method-in-matlab), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370486/how-to-use-newton-raphson-method-in-matlab-to-find-an-equation-root).  Even more on the web like [Matlab Central](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331218484978&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4313&ei=MchYT-qgE4vrggf19u2hCw&usg=AFQjCNGvurpUbKxzX0vXkYsxpqn5gh4LGg&sig2=g-iz-dlqOrKHcKvNN6xYsA), or other educational sites like [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331218566528&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://elm.eeng.dcu.ie/~ee317/Matlab_Examples/iter/tutinfo%255B1%255D.htm&ei=MchYT-qgE4vrggf19u2hCw&usg=AFQjCNE5Yz4na1z2AOV4y822SokJ36f9Eg&sig2=ZlcpvLlY0pbaxGYeO6u3pQ).  So, I think you could have come to the table a little more prepared.  I'll put my two cents in here as far as the method I like the best.

```
function x = newton(f,dfdx,x0,tolerance)
err = Inf;
x = x0;
while abs(err) > tolerance
   xPrev = x;
   x = xPrev - f(xPrev)./dfdx(xPrev);
   % stop criterion: (f(x) - 0) < tolerance
   err = f(x); % 
   % stop criterion: change of x < tolerance
   % err = x - xPrev;
end

f = @(x) ((x-4).^2-4);
dfdx = @(x)(2.*(x-4));
x0 = 1;
xRoot = newton(@f,@dfdx,x0,1e-10);
```

f(x) = 4wd<sup>2</sup>(1-x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> - abc<sup>3</sup>x√(π<sup>2</sup>*(1-x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>+16*x<sup>2</sup>)

So just differentiate the above equation with respect to *x* and then you have your df/dx.  Plug the equations into the file handles and run the routine!  Also, I'm fine with moving this to SE Math, but I don't know how to do that either.  :-)