# Secant Method in While

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I have a secant method in for loop trying to change it to while loop but problem is just showing one iteration and I want to make it like for loop but in while loop.

The code of **For** loop:

```
    clc;clear;
    x0=1;
    x1=0;
    f=@(x) 3*x+sin(x)-exp(x)
    if abs(x0) <abs(x1)
        t=x0;
        x0=x1;
        x1=t;
    end
    for i=1:5
        x2=x1-(f(x1)*((x0-x1)/(f(x0)-f(x1))))
        disp([x0,  x1,  x2,  f(x2)]);
        x0=x1;
        x1=x2;
    end
```

and this is my **while** loop code:

```
clc; clear;
 x0=1;
 x1=0;
 error=1
 tol=0.00001;
 f=@(x) 3*x+sin(x)-exp(x)
 if abs(f(x0)) < abs(f(x1))
     t=x0;
     x0=x1;
     x1=t;
 end
 x2=x1-(f(x1)*((x0-x1)/(f(x0)-f(x1))))
 while(abs(f(x2))<tol)

         disp(x1);

         x0=x1;
         x1=x2;
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are not modifying `x2` inside the loop so your `while` loop will either not run or loop endlessly.  As ViG pointed out your logical condition is backwards as you want to loop while your error is greater than the tolerance.  Also, it is a good idea to add a maximum loop count to the while condition in the event it does not converge.   Finally you defined `error` but never used it.  So I made it more clear what the code is doing by adding it to the loop for readability.

```
x0=1;
x1=0;
error=1;
tol=0.00001;
f=@(x) 3*x+sin(x)-exp(x);
loopCount = 0;
maxNumLoops = 100;

if abs(f(x0)) < abs(f(x1))
    t=x0;
    x0=x1;
    x1=t;    
end
while(abs(error)>tol) && loopCount < maxNumLoops  
    loopCount = loopCount +1;
    x2=x1-(f(x1)*((x0-x1)/(f(x0)-f(x1))));
    error = f(x2);
    x0=x1;
    x1=x2;    
end
if loopCount >= maxNumLoops  
   disp('Method did not converge!!') 
end
```

Comment: thank you so much, i have a newton method to in for but i don't know how to make it in while can you help me with it too?

Comment: You can post it as a new question & I will take a look when I get some time.   Otherwise someone else might get to it first.  However, you might want to use this site's search function.  There are several Matlab Newton Raphson method question son here already that might contain what you are looking for.  Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640295/1106634

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't enther the while loop is because `abs(f(x2))<tol` isn't satisfied. I guess you want to refine your result till the next step is smaller than `tol`. In that case you should use `while(abs(f(x2))>tol)`, because then, the loop will repeat itself till `abs(f(x2))<=tol`. Also don't forgot to put the function of `x2` inside the while-loop, otherwise `x2` won't be updated, and you'll loop indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code, maybe it helps you:

```
secant <- function(fn, x0, x1, tol, max.iter){
xn.min1 <- x0
xn <- x1
iter <- 1
while((abs(xn-xn.min1) > tol) && (iter < max.iter)){
  xn.plus1 <- xn - f(xn)*(xn-xn.min1)/(f(xn)-f(xn.min1))
  xn.min1 <- xn
  xn <- xn.plus1
  iter <- iter + 1
}
if (abs(xn.plus1 - xn) > tol){
  cat("failed to converge\n")
  return(NULL)
} else {
  return(xn.plus1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your stopping criteria. See my code for a working example.

```
x.n.minus.1 <- 0.5
x.n <- 6
iter <- 1
while ((abs(x.n-x.n.minus.1) > tol) && (iter < max.iter)) {
  x.n.plus.1 <- x.n - f.acc(x.n)*(x.n-x.n.minus.1)/(f.acc(x.n)-f.acc(x.n.minus.1))
  x.n.minus.1 <- x.n
  x.n <- x.n.plus.1
  iter <- iter + 1
  cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x.n is:", x.n, "\n")
}
```